# Other/the other confusion in a sentence

Tags: meaning, word-choice, pronouns, definite-articles

Consider the following sentence (it is a real medical condition)

> These people have blue skin. We should let them get in touch with
>   other sufferers.

I would prefer using **the other** sufferers as **other sufferers** could mean people suffering from anything. Do I get it correctly?

Comment: It's fairly obvious "other sufferers" means *others suffering from **the same** condition*, so there's no semantic (or grammatical) reason to *require* an article. If you *do* include it, the implication is that the writer has a specific group of "other sufferers" in mind (and, to a lesser extent, an implication that those are ***all** the other sufferers*).

Comment: How does it imply the suffer from the same condition if there is not the article? What about sufferers suffering from other diseases?

Comment: @ Vivarion: What about people who are suffering because they sprained their ankle, or had too much to drink last night? You don't think of *them* in your current context. Why should you be worried someone might think you're talking about people who suffer from *diseases* other than the one causing blue skin, but not people who are suffering for reasons other than disease? The implication that it's sufferers with "blue skin disease" is because *that's what's mentioned in the preceding sentence.*

Answer (score 2):

You would say *the other sufferers* only if you are referring to some sufferers who have already been mentioned. If you mean sufferers in general, then *other sufferers* without the article is what you want.

Comment: And what if I want to refer to a part of a group? E.g. there is 20 sufferers. 10 died but the other sufferers are still alive - that would be correct, would it not? And they are not the same, already mentioned.

Comment: I mean, I have read some examples, e.g.: There are 5 apples. I ate two, what should I do with the other apples? Could it work without the definite article?

Comment: English articles are difficult for foreign learners, and I assume you are one. You won’t understand articles in a few questions and answers here. You really need to consult a qualified English teacher, or a grammar book written for foreign learners.

Comment: You may also find [ell.se] useful.

Comment: In both the cases you mention, you have already identified a *specific* group (of other sufferers or apples) and are referring to the remainder of that group. In your question "*the* other sufferers" implies either (1) (as Barrie has said) you have already mentioned a specific group of other sufferers; or (2) you are referring to ***all*** other sufferers (potentially worldwide); whereas I assume you are referring to getting in contact with *some* other sufferers. You could include the word "some", but that is implicit from the wording "other sufferers" (**without** "the").

Answer (score 0):

*Other sufferers* could (just) mean *sufferers of this or other diseases*, but it is very unlikely to, because the word *sufferer* requires a condition. i.e.

> I am a sufferer

is incoherent unless the context somehow identifies the condition that I suffer. So *other sufferers* is similarly incoherent unless the condition is supplied from context - which it is here.